# Delta-Y transformation and dual circuits

Tags: dual, y-to-delta, delta-to-y

I have been thinking about the relationship between delta-Y transforms and the dual of a given circuit and I am confused about a sort of overlap I see.

[image]

Take a delta circuit with resistances as shown, with internal current $$q,$$ and external incoming current $$k_1,k_2,k_3.$$ To go to the equivalent Y-circuit we effectively integrate out the internal (mesh) current, and we get a Y circuit whose resistances are given by $$R_1=\frac{R_bR_c}{R_a+R_b+R_c},\,R_2=\frac{R_aR_c}{R_a+R_b+R_c},\,R_3=\frac{R_bR_a}{R_a+R_b+R_c}.$$
The power of the delta circuit was
$$P_\Delta=R_a(k_1+k_2+k_3+q)^2+R_b(k_1+k_2+q)^2+R_c(k_1+q)^2,$$

which transformed to the power of the Y circuit
$$P_Y=R_1k_1^2+R_2k_2^2+R_3k_3^2.$$

Now if I instead want to consider the dual circuit of the delta circuit, I would take whatever equation, say the power of the delta circuit, and replace the resistance by the capacitance and the current by the voltage differences, so the power of the dual is
$$P_d=\sigma_a(v_1-v_0)^2+\sigma_b(v_2-v_0)^2+\sigma_c(v_3-v_0)^2,\quad \text{where}\quad\sigma_i=\frac{1}{R_i},\,i={a,b,c}.$$

What confuses me is that I have read that we can go from the current description to the voltage description (and hence to the dual circuit) by Fourier transforming the delta circuit equations and inverting the resistance (i.e. writing the capacitance). However, Fourier transforming the current, in particular the internal one, is essentially what we do when we calculate the equivalent Y circuit, since it requires us to integrate over the current, so it seems like we are also kind of doing the delta-Y transform at the same time.

I am just overall very confused about the relationship between the two things: the delta-Y equivalent and the dual diagram, especially because they give something with the same geometry.

Comment: I think momentum and momenta aren't the correct translations into English.

Comment: Oops, I'm actually applying these kind of circuit rules to particle physics, where momentum is the analogue, so out of habit I wrote momentum. Changed it now, thanks

Comment: @furious.neutrino  See the Appendix starting on page 20 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0606053.pdf) and then perhaps also [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.07764.pdf) for a paper on a degree preserving version of delta-wye. I am not sure if either of these help. I admit I'm not entirely sure about your question. It's perhaps a little too terse. That said, I was reminded of those two papers.